# VIM-easytags for single-file projects

Tags: vim, vim-plugin

#### Problem concerns [this plugin](https://github.com/xolox/vim-easytags) for VIM.

It works great for big projects with multiple files in multiple directories, but sometimes I would like to have separate tags for every file in X directory.

#### For example:

I am solving [Project Euler](https://projecteuler.net/archives) problems. Solutions for those problems aren't very complicated, basically every solution is 1-file-program. I obviously store those solutions in one directory (Let's call it X directory) and here is the problem.

Is it possible to make easytags treat every file in my X directory as independent project? I want it to highlight things defined only in file I am editing at the moment. I want every single file in this directory to be treated as independent project.

Is there easy way to do so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure you absolutely need ctags for that?

You can use `gd`/`gD` to jump to the local/global definition of the symbol under the cursor or things like `[I` or `:dlist`.

See `:help gd` and `:help include-search`.

Comment: I like easytags, because it highlights methods names. As there seems to be no other solution, I will just turn it off and use gd/gD as u said. Thanks!